# An improved qsort() function in c

Tags: c, sorting

Suppose we are sorting a 1D array using qsort(), is there a simple way to retrieve from an element of the sorted array the index tis very element had when it was indexed in the array before it was sorted. Let's say c[N] become sorted as d[N], how to find from an integer i, j such that c[j]=d[i] ? When I mean a simple way, does qsort (with some additional parameter) stores this kind of information (bijection between indexations before an after sorting) or does it exist a qsort improved function that could sort and retrieve easily this kind of information ?

Comment: You can do that manually , I mean get the indexes before and after sorting.. right ?

Comment: are you talking about posix' `qsort(3)`?

Comment: @hroptatyr `qsort()` is part of the C standard library, POSIX doesn't change its functionality in any way.

Comment: @Daniel yes, I was confused because the OP was talking about an improved version, and I was going to offer a resolution with a different signature (which obviously would not be a drop-in replacement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you populate the initial array with a structure like this:

```
struct IndexedInteger {
  int value;
  int index;
}
```

You would then need to fill the indices in a loop:

```
void addIndices(IndexedInteger * array, size_t num) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    array[i].index = i;
  }
}
```

Then you will sort your array:

```
int compareIndexed(const void * elem1, const void * elem2) {
  IndexedInteger * i1, *i2;
  i1 = (IndexedInteger*)elem1;
  i2 = (IndexedInteger*)elem2;
  return i1->value - i2->value;
}

void sortArray(IndexedInteger * array, size_t num) {
  qsort(array, num, sizeof(IndexedInteger), compareIndexed);
}
```

Then you will have your array sorted, with initial indices.

Disclaimer: I'm writing this quite fast, there might be mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a `struct` which holds your data (in this case, an integer) and also an integer which corresponds to the index of the position where it was initially on your array. To clarify,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct myData {
    int data;
    int orig_pos; // will hold the original position of data on your array
};

int myData_compare (const void* a, const void* b) {

    return ((struct myData*)a)->data - ((struct myData*)b)->data;
}

int main () {

    size_t N = 10; // size of your array
    struct myData* array = (struct myData*) malloc(N * sizeof(struct myData));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i].data     = N - i; // array will hold 10,9,8,7,...1 in this order
        array[i].orig_pos = i;
    }
    qsort(array, N, sizeof(struct myData), &myData_compare);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("\ndata: %d, orig_pos: %d", array[i].data, array[i].orig_pos);
    }
    return 0;
}
```