# Using qsort in Cython to get a sorting index/permutation

Tags: sorting, cython, qsort

**Overview**

There are a few questions similar to this one but they are all slightly different. To be clear, if `values` is an array of integers, I want to find `perm` such that `sorted_values` (`values` sorted by some comparison operator), is given by

```
sorted_values[i] = values[perm[i]]
```

**Step 1**

How to do it in C? Well `qsort` requires declaring a comparison function to tell you whether one value is greater than another. If we make `values` a global variable, then we can exploit this comparison function to sort an array `perm` initially set to `0:N-1` (where `N` is the length of `values`) by not comparing `perm[i]` vs `perm[j]` but instead comparing `values[perm[i]]` vs `values[perm[j]]`. See this [link](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/83197-sorting-getting-permutation-index-array.html). Some example C code:

```
// sort_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *values;

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( values[*(int*)a] - values[*(int*)b] );
}

int main () {
   int i;
   int n = 5;
   int *perm;

   // Assign memory
   values = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   perm = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

   // Set values to random values between 0 and 99
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) values[i] = rand() % 100;

   // Set perm initially to 0:n-1
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) perm[i] = i;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", values[i]);

   qsort(perm, n, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nThe sorting permutation is: \n");
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", perm[i]);

   free(values);
   free(perm);

   printf("\n");

   return(0);
}
```

Of course the trick is defining `values` globally, so the `cmpfunc` can see it.

**Step 2**

How to do it in Cython? Unfortunately I cannot get Cython to use the same trick with values declared globally. My best attempt is the following based off the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254146/sort-memoryview-in-cython), however the difference is that they just sort an array they do not need to get the indexing/permutation.

```
# sort_test_c.pyx
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport qsort

# Try declaring global variable for the sort function
cpdef long[:] values

cdef int cmpfunc (const void *a , const void *b) nogil:
    cdef long a_v = (<long *> a)[0] 
    cdef long b_v = (<long *> b)[0]
    return (values[a_v] - values[b_v]);

def sort(long[:] py_values, long[:] perm, int N):
    # Assign to global
    values = py_values

    # Make sure perm is 0:N-1
    for i in range(N):
        perm[i] = i

    # Perform sort
    qsort(&perm[0], N, perm.strides[0], &cmpfunc)
```

This can be compiled using

```
cythonize -i sort_test_c.pyx
```

and tested with the script

```
# sort_test.py
from sort_test_c import sort
import numpy as np

n = 5
values = np.random.randint(0, 100, n).astype(int)
perm = np.empty(n).astype(int)

sort(values, perm, n)
```

This however complains about our global variable `values` i.e.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'values' referenced before assignment
Exception ignored in: 'sort_test_c.cmpfunc
```

and the sorting permutation is not correct (unless the `values` are already ordered in which case it is luck as `perm` always returns the array `0:4`). How can I fix this?

Comment: Global variables in Python and Cython are at module level rather than truely global. (I'm not convinced that this approach to the problem is the best though)

Comment: I agree, I dislike the solution of having to use a global variable but I can't see a way around it with the `qsort` API

Comment: [struct of values and indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12212516/4657412) looks to be the standard approach. Alternatively you could sort an array of pointers instead and work out the indexes from that.

Comment: The link is a much nicer way of doing it, for some reason I didn't think of using a structure. Now the compare function API makes more sense.